# Using SpriteBatch with BasicEffects and layerDepth creates negative Z values?

Tags: xna, spritebatch, depth-buffer

Simply: Why don't all of these sprites draw? What do I need to do to make them draw?

I'm trying to use SpriteBatch.Draw with the layerDepth parameter to help reduce overdrawn. However I can't get it to work properly. It keeps outputting negative Z values when I try to use it with AlphaTestEffect! I've created a basic test case below to show the problem of.

The code for creating the effects and matrixes are based on this :["SpriteBatch and custom shaders in XNA Game Studio 4.0"](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905162400/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/05/spritebatch-and-custom-shaders-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) from the XNA blog.

I think the projection matrix given should make sense, looking at the docs for CreateOrthographicOffCenter. But for some reason it doesn't! Can any one figure out why and tell me, please?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace SpriteBatchTest
{
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        BasicEffect basicEffect;
        AlphaTestEffect alphaTestEffect;
        Texture2D mysprite;


        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            base.Initialize();

            Viewport viewport = this.GraphicsDevice.Viewport;
            Matrix projection = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0, viewport.Width, viewport.Height, 0, 0, 1);
            Matrix halfPixelOffset = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0);

            basicEffect = new BasicEffect(this.GraphicsDevice);
            basicEffect.World = Matrix.Identity;
            basicEffect.View = Matrix.Identity;
            basicEffect.Projection = halfPixelOffset * projection;

            basicEffect.TextureEnabled = true;
            basicEffect.VertexColorEnabled = true;




            alphaTestEffect = new AlphaTestEffect(GraphicsDevice);
            alphaTestEffect.VertexColorEnabled = false;
            alphaTestEffect.DiffuseColor = Color.White.ToVector3();
            alphaTestEffect.AlphaFunction = CompareFunction.Greater;
            alphaTestEffect.ReferenceAlpha = 0;
            alphaTestEffect.World = Matrix.Identity;
            alphaTestEffect.View = Matrix.Identity;
            alphaTestEffect.Projection = halfPixelOffset * projection;

        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {



            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            mysprite = Content.Load<Texture2D>("test");

            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }

        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed ||
                Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                this.Exit();

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            this.GraphicsDevice.Clear(ClearOptions.Target | ClearOptions.DepthBuffer, Color.CornflowerBlue, 1.0f, 0);

            spriteBatch.Begin();
            //drawn
            spriteBatch.Draw(mysprite, new Vector2(100, 100), Color.White);
            //drawn
            spriteBatch.Draw(mysprite, new Vector2(500, 100), null, Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero,
                 Vector2.One, SpriteEffects.None, 0.50f);
            spriteBatch.End();

            spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.PointClamp,
                DepthStencilState.Default, RasterizerState.CullNone, basicEffect);
            //drawn
            spriteBatch.Draw(mysprite, new Vector2(150, 150), Color.White);
            //neg z, not drawn
            spriteBatch.Draw(mysprite, new Vector2(500, 150), null, Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero,
                 Vector2.One, SpriteEffects.None, 0.50f);
            spriteBatch.End();

            spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.PointClamp,
                DepthStencilState.Default, RasterizerState.CullNone,
                alphaTestEffect);
            //drawn
            spriteBatch.Draw(mysprite, new Vector2(200, 200), Color.White);
            //not draw - negative Z
            spriteBatch.Draw(mysprite, new Vector2(500, 200), null, Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero,
                Vector2.One, SpriteEffects.None, 0.50f);
            spriteBatch.End();

            //drawn
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            spriteBatch.Draw(mysprite, new Vector2(200, 100), null, Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero,
                            Vector2.One, SpriteEffects.None, 0.50f);
            spriteBatch.End();

            //not draw - negative Z
            spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.PointClamp,
                DepthStencilState.Default, RasterizerState.CullNone, basicEffect);
            spriteBatch.Draw(mysprite, new Vector2(250, 150), null, Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero,
                Vector2.One, SpriteEffects.None, 0.60f);
            spriteBatch.End();

            //not draw - negative Z
            spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.PointClamp,
                DepthStencilState.Default, RasterizerState.CullNone, alphaTestEffect);
            spriteBatch.Draw(mysprite, new Vector2(300, 200), null, Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero,
                            Vector2.One, SpriteEffects.None, 0.70f);
            spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see two unusual things with this code sample. First, you are using `CompareFunction.Greater`, usually for depth functions I've seen `CompareFunction.LessEqual` used. Second, your use of `SpriteSortMode.Deferred` means you cannot be sure which order your sprites will be drawn. Until you solve this problem, I would switch that to `SpriteSortMode.Immediate`.

Comment: I forgot about this question :) The problem was that XNA sprite's use a RHS and DX uses a LHS. So my Z values would get flipped, as XNA has positive Z going into the screen and DX has negative Z.

Comment: Could you mark this question as closed then please?

Comment: @simonalexander2005 The question should not be marked "closed;" closure is for questions that are no on-topic or not appropriate here (and is something voted on by the community, it is not something the asker can do).

Comment: @Pod What simonalexander probably meant to say is that you should post your solution as an *answer* (and not a comment). Then, after a brief timeout, you should be able to mark that answer as "the" answer, marking the question as "answered" (not "closed").

Comment: @JoshPetrie yes, that's what I meant - sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that XNA sprite's use a Right Hand coordinate system and the DirectX API by default uses a Left Hand coordinate system by default. So my Z values would get flipped as XNA has positive Z going into the screen and DX has negative Z going into the screen.